# how to prevent 401 unauthorized error message in browser console

Tags: angular, angular5

I am new to angular 5. now i have call one api on page load in angular. now if there 401 error then it will show message in browser console. now i want to not show that error, so how can i do this. as i have try to catch that error in service call but still getting issue. 
my code in service:-

```
getToken(): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    return this._http.get(this.hostUrl + '/token').pipe(
      map((response: Response) => <ApiResponse>response.json())).catch((e: any) => {
        if (e.status === 401) {
            return Observable.empty();
        }
    });
  }
```

as you see i throw Observable.empty() but still i get error show in red mark in browser console. please help me to prevent this.

thank you,

Comment: You can just hide it. If you are using Chrome: DevTools->Settings->Console->Hide network messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible!

The `http` errors are browser specific and its quite not possible to remove them from browser console. However you can handle the error in your code in subscribe block,

.subscribe takes 3 function call back

- suceess
- error
- complere

You can define error handling in your error block to handle that but still it will console log the 401 error in the console.

```
this.xxxService.ttt(someProps).subscribe(
  (response) => {  // this is the response success

    // do something in success
  }, (error) => {
    // do something on error
    // here you can check if status code is 401 then do something.
  }, (compoele) => {
    // its like on complete of the observable

  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

you could do that by using Angular HttpClient Interceptors. See the following links

- [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)
- [Aligator.io](https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/)

Comment: Even interceptors will not help. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68729197/prevent-401-error-browser-console-angular.